# how to set the number to become 4 decimal places

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code

```
    tableyy = final.style.apply(color, axis=None).set_table_attributes('border="" class = "dataframe table table-hover table-bordered"').set_precision(4).render()
```

**set_precision(4)** I wish to make it my value to become 4 decimal places, but for some value still return me 5 decimal places for example 0.03045. So anyone can share me how to replace the set_precision so that my value all return in 4 decimal places but not 4 significant value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look into the [`DataFrame.round(decimals=0, *args, **kwargs)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) method.  I think the following code sample would do what you are asking:

```py
tableyy = final.round(4).style.apply(
  color, axis=None
).set_table_attributes(
  'border="" class = "dataframe table table-hover table-bordered"'
).render()
```

Here is some code I used to test this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
  np.random.random([3,3]), 
  columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], 
  index=['first', 'second', 'third']
)

table = df.round(2).style.applymap(
  lambda val: 'color: red' if val > 0.5 else 'color: black'
).set_table_attributes(
  'border="" class = "dataframe table table-hover table-border:red"'
).render()

with open('test.html', 'w+') as f:
  f.write(table)
```

Then opening the resulting test.html file in the browser shows a table where each column has at most 2 decimal places for me.

Comment: I get error which is 'Styler' object has no attribute 'round'

Comment: @ShiJieTio I have updated the code sample and it should work now, the `round` method needs to be called on the DataFrame object, not the Styler.

Comment: thanks but now cann work the number still didn't not conver to 4 decimal place

Comment: I'm not certain why the sample code isn't converting to 4 decimal places correctly for you, sorry.  If you take a look at my updated answer I've included a test script I wrote to test the `round` method, and it works correctly for me when I open the resulting html file in my browser.

Comment: I still fail to do that any suggestion to adjust at Django there?